# data format error in association rule learning R

Tags: r, associations, dataformat

I tried to search other posts in R related to this, but did not find duplicated questions(at least to my efforts). I know I need a priori function in library("a rules") though.

I have a large array file A that each row is a list

```
user1:  [1,2,3,4]      # [1,2,3,4] is the itemList purchased by this user
user2:  [4]
................
```

I want to find items that tend to be purchased together. How should I proceed? It seems I need to convert the data to "transaction" format file also.

So I did

```
temp <- split(A, 1:nrow(A))   # temp is now a list of lists
B <- as(temp, "transactions")
```

But I got the error "Error in asMethod(object) : can coerce list with atomic components only"
Anyone can help?

I googled this example and run the following code without problem

```
a_list <- list(c("I1","I2","I5"), c("I2","I4"), c("I2","I3"), c("I1","I2","I4"), c("I1","I3"),c("I2","I3"),c("I1","I3"),
c("I1","I2","I3","I5"), c("I1","I2","I3") )

names(a_list) <- paste("T",c(1:9), "00", sep = "")
table5_1 <- as(a_list, "transactions")
```

Both of temp (in my code) and a_list are of class list, however

```
     a_list[1]
[[1]]
[1] "I1" "I2" "I5"

     temp[1]
 $`1`
 $`1`$`1`
 [1] 1,2,3,4
```

How should I correct this? Is this due to the factor my temp file was derived from a data frame?

Thanks

Comment: It would be useful to understand how you have the data in R, could you post the results of `dput(head(A))`?

Comment: structure(list(`user1` = c(1,2,3,4), `user2` = 4,......), .Dim = 6L, .Dimnames = list(
    c("user1", "user2", "user3", ....)))

Comment: The difference between `a_list` and `temp` seems to be that each element in `temp` is a "list" that contains a vector whereas in `a_list` each element is a vector. You could try something like `as(lapply(temp, "[[", 1), "transactions")`. For comparison see how `as(lapply(a_list, list), "transactions")` fails. BTW, to select an _element_ of a "list" use `mylist[[1]]` and not `mylist[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error and couldn't figure it out. Finally, I realized that I had null values coming through in the description/item field. I'd check for null/empty strings coming through as that might be the issue (Assuming you have already removed duplicate records for one transaction).

Comment: This should be comment. When you are not clear about OP's question or for suggestion please use comment not the answer option.