# create list based on data frame in R

Tags: r, list

I have a data frame A in the following format

```
user         item
10000000     1      # each user is a 8 digits integer, item is up to 5 digits integer
10000000     2
10000000     3
10000001     1
10000001     4
..............
```

What I want is a list B, with users' names as the name of list elements, list element is a vector of items corresponding to this user.

e.g

```
B = list(c(1,2,3),c(1,4),...)
```

I also need to paste names to B.  To apply association rule learning, items need to be convert to characters

Originally I used `tapply(A$user,A$item, c)`, this makes it not compatible with association rule package. See my post:

[data format error in association rule learning R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884193/data-format-error-in-association-rule-learning-r?noredirect=1#comment34925811_22884193)

But @sgibb's solution seems also generates an array, not a list.

```
library("arules")
temp <- as(C, "transactions")    # C is output using @sgibb's solution

throws error: Error in as(C, "transactions") : 
no method or default for coercing “array” to “transactions”
```

Comment: Please please please use `dput` to share your data. [See here for reasons and more details](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061), it makes it much easier to help.

Comment: `?dlply` or `?tapply`

Comment: Also, in your previous question you mentioned `split`. See `split(A$item, A$user)`

Comment: @alexis_laz, you are right. It made me whole afternoon trying to dig out the bug

Comment: @alexis_laz, would you provide your solution? I am really tired after whole afternoon trying.

Comment: alexis_laz, are we applying association rule correctly if we directly use split function without "tapply", i.e, correct items together

Comment: @Jin the output of `tapply` and `split` is the same. The only difference is `class(tapply(...)) == "array"` and `class(split(...)) == "list")`.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot to both alexis_laz and sgibb

Comment: @alexis_laz, your solution split(A$item, A$user) will create duplicated items in a lot of users' itemList, how to remove these duplicates? I already tried loop combined with unique, but failed. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps, try something like `lapply(split(A$item, A$user), unique)`. Should there be duplicated items, though? If not, maybe you 've made a miscalculation somewhere when building `A`? I only say this, because neither `split` nor `tapply` have anything to do with a possible duplication of values.

Comment: finally it worked, thanks so much for your efforts, @alexis_laz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `tapply`:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("
user         item
10000000     1
10000000     2
10000000     3
10000001     1
10000001     4"), header=TRUE)

B <- tapply(df$item, df$user, FUN=as.character)
B
# $`10000000`
# [1] "1" "2" "3"
#
# $`10000001`
# [1] "1" "4"
```

EDIT: I do not know the *arules* package, but here the solution proposed by @alexis_laz:

```
library("arules")
as(split(df$item, df$user), "transactions")
# transactions in sparse format with
#  2 transactions (rows) and
#  4 items (columns)
```

Comment: your solution provides an array, not a list. Assume your output is B, brand_table <- as(B, "transactions") will complain (after you install library("a rules") )

Comment: @Jin: You should have mentioned the *arules* package, your aim and your link to the previous question from the beginning. See my edit.

Comment: you are not using B in the as command? why use split(df$item, df$user) here?

Comment: @Jin because it is a short example. You could use `B <- split(df$item, df$user); as(B, "transactions")` instead. (And my `B` answer before the edit was the answer to the original question (and to the title of the question).)

Comment: I see your point. But are you using association rule correctly if we try to collect all items belonging to same user first? We can directly split?

Comment: @Jin I have no idea. As I already mentioned, I do not know what the *arules* package is doing neither what an object of a `transactions` class should do or should look like. I just provided an answer to your question. The input is technical correct but I don't know anything about the logical correctness  of the input.

Comment: B <- split(df$item, df$user); as(B, "transactions") failed because in some user's transactions, items are appeared more than once, (i.e, duplicated). I tried to use a loop and set to remove these but failed

Comment: @Jin: `as(lapply(split(df$item, df$user), unique), "transactions")`